# Custom Listview adaptor ImageView Click

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

Currently I have implemented a custom listview which has an adaptor, within the listview row is an ImageView which I have made clickable:

```
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = _items[position];
        var view = convertView;
        ListViewHolder listViewHolder;
        if (view == null)
        {
            listViewHolder = new ListViewHolder();
            var inflater = LayoutInflater.FromContext(_context);
            view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.foorow, parent, false);
            listViewHolder.cImage = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.cImg);        
            listViewHolder.cText = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.cTxt);
            listViewHolder.cSet = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.cSet);
            listViewHolder.cType = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.cType);
            listViewHolder.cId = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.cId);
            listViewHolder.cImage.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                _listFragment.ShowLargeImage(item);
            };
            view.Tag = listViewHolder;
        }
        else
        {
            listViewHolder = (ListViewHolder)view.Tag;
        }

        if (item != null)
        {
            try
            {
                Glide.With(_context)
                    .Load(item.ImageUrl)
                    .DiskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.All)
                    //todo .Placeholder()
                    .Into(listViewHolder.cImage);
                listViewHolder.cText.Text = item.Name;
                listViewHolder.cSet.Text = item.Set;
                listViewHolder.cId.Text = item.Id;
                listViewHolder.cType.Text = string.Join(",", item.Types.Select(i => i));
                if (!listViewHolder.cImage.HasOnClickListeners)
                {
                    listViewHolder.cImage.Click += (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        _listFragment.ShowLargeImage(item);
                    };
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var xx = ex;
            }

        }

        return view;
    }
```

The issue I am experiencing is that when clicking one of the ImageViews a few rows down its actually returning the incorrect item, and therefore displaying the wrong image.

I am guessing its something to do with that way the listview is held in memory and the positioning but I cannot work it out.

I have tried setting the imageview click tag and reusing this but this didn't seem to help.

Comment: If the view is not null, u should also set view onclick method

Comment: Store the item (or a reference) in your `ListViewHolder`, in your handler retrieve the item and use that item in your `ShowLargeImage`

Comment: @uguboz This causes a "double" click effect where its called twice, once with the wrong item and once with the correct

Comment: @SushiHangover You're suggesting passing through a reference over an actual item?

Comment: instead of `listViewHolder.cImage.Click +=` try `listViewHolder.cImage.SetOnClickListener`

Comment: @jaymarvels You are using `item` (a captured var in your anonymous method) and the value of `item` changes every time `GetView` is called...

Comment: Can you please share the code of `ShowLargeImage`?